# Calculate Signal noise ratio on Wifi Signal

Tags: linux, signal-processing

Is there any implementation or library that I can use to calculate the SNR (Signal noise ratio) of a wifi signal on a linux machine which is connected via an ad-hoc network?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Currently I'm facing the same problem. I also would like to obtain the RSSI of each individual message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can include `<linux/wireless.h>` and see what `ioctl()` returns on a `SIOCGIWSPY`.

The struct `iw_quality` will contain some of the information you are looking for: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/wireless.h?v=2.6.11.8#L504

This is what `iwlist` does internally.

Answer (score -1):

You can use iwlist command like this:

```
iwlist scan
```

It will produce some output like this:

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ...
```

May be you are interested in the reported "Quality".

Comment: no, he is interested in calculating SNR accurately.